# SEO friendly query vars

Tags: query, redirect, regex

I have an issue with a PHP form and the query vars it generates to fetch certain posts. An example of a generated URL could look like this:

```
siteurl/properties/?state=georgia&type=industrial
```

The posts within those taxonomies do appear just fine. The thing is that I'd like to have a better URL, like:

```
siteurl/properties/georgia/industrial
```

I have tried with a few redirect options. For example, with the redirection plugin, I can achieve that if a user visits:

```
siteurl/properties/georgia/industrial
```

The sites behave the same as if the user would search for:

```
siteurl/properties/?state=georgia&type=industrial
```

But that's not exactly it, how can I invert that behavior so that when the form submits the URL it looks more SEO friendly and it works as it did before? Meaning it actually fetches the posts from those taxonomies as well. Is that even doable?

Comment: I imagine this should be possible but you would need some JavaScript magic. When a form submits by `get` you see the `get` params in the URL. Another way might be to have it `post` the data only to quickly and quietly 301/302 redirect to the SEO friendly version.

Comment: The answer was indeed using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I made this work by using Javascript:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;

var prettyURL = currentURL.replace('?', '').replace('state=', '').replace('&type=', '/');

window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/" + prettyURL);
```